# Find opposite transformation of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to add a `SKShapeNode` drawn from my `SKScene` to a `SKSpriteNode`. The `SKSpriteNode` may already have some transformations that automatically translate to the `SKShapeNode`, which I don't want to happen. I've added a screenshot of the way the shapenode jumps after adding. I have also added my code where I add the shape node as a child and apply some opposite transformations to the node (works fine in some cases, but for example when I scale, move and rotate the robot, the drawing jumps to another position).

```
    func addMaskPath(_ path: CGPath) {
    let drawing = MaskLayer(withPath: path)
    drawing.zRotation = -zRotation

    drawing.xScale = drawing.xScale / xScale
    drawing.yScale = drawing.yScale / yScale

    drawing.position.x = (drawing.position.x - position.x) / xScale
    drawing.position.y = (drawing.position.y - position.y) / yScale

    drawing.position.y = drawing.position.y*cos(zRotation) - drawing.position.x*sin(zRotation)
    drawing.position.x = -drawing.position.y*sin(zRotation) + drawing.position.x*cos(zRotation)

    cropMask?.eraserMask?.addChild(drawing)
}
```

MaskLayer is a SKShapeNode. How do I easily find the transformations of my SKSpriteNode and apply them the opposite way to my SKShapeNode so my drawing will visually stay exactly the same?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPhFg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add your `SKShapeNode` to a `SKSpriteNode` if you don't want it to inherit its transformation.

I suggest having a parent `SKNode` that'll hold your `SKSpriteNode` and  add your `SKShapeNode` to the parent `SKNode` instead of the `SKSpriteNode`